# Custom Bootstrap variables not working with Rails 6 and Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

I'm implementing Bootstrap 4.4 in a Rails 6 app using Webpacker and the theming isn't working in production.

I overrode some Bootstrap variables and put the custom theming in a separate file called `bootstrap_variables.scss`. I made sure to import Bootstrap's `functions` before the custom variables in the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file as outlined [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23331) and [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25361).

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap_variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

When I run the app locally it works fine. When I try to push to production (Heroku) the build fails and I get the following error:

```
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
on line 181:43 of app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_variables.scss, in function `darken`
from line 181:43 of app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_variables.scss
$link-hover-color: darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
```

That references the following lines in the custom `bootstrap_variables.scss` file:

```
$link-color:                              theme-color("primary") !default;
$link-decoration:                         none !default;
$link-hover-color:                        darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
```

Why might this be working locally but not in production?